# What is the canonical way to obtain a review of a moderator action

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-answers

An answer of mine was deleted by a mod, and I'd like somebody (possibly the mod himself) to take a second look. The "Undelete" button does not work for mod-deleted posts.

What's the canonical way to trigger a review of a moderator action? None of the mandatory tags for a post here on meta seem to fit, not even "discussion", judging by the tag description ("no clear-cut answer"?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a post like you did with a link to the question/answer that you want reviewed is how to go about it.

The other way is to use the contact link at the bottom of the page to contact Stack Exchange and provide them the same details.

https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: "post like you did": Support tag?

Comment: Yes, I think that is an appropriate tag for the question, though discussion could also work as well.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It appears that this answered your question as your question addressing the deleted answer appears to have gotten it undeleted.

Comment: It did :-).....